# Is there a way for eslint extension on vscode to show all errors in a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

currently the extension only shows 1000 errors from the start and rest are ignored, my file is big and fixing all errors may take a time, so fixing only some errors which are related to the part of the file i am working on.

Comment: you have a problem with >1000 errors in your file and you HAVE to fix them sometime, so fix them NOW, Comment out the part your not working on

Comment: fixing all will take time then fixing te errors wile adding new features